# Trim String/Text in Flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

Hi I tried to trim a link in flutter

Currently I am looking into regexp but I think that is not possible

This is the link in full:

`http://sales.local/api/v1/payments/454/ticket/verify?token=jhvycygvjhbknm.eyJpc3MiOiJodH`

What I am trying to do is to trim the link like this:

`http://sales.local/api/v1/payments/454`

Kindly advise on best practise to trim string/text in flutter. Thanks!

Comment: Why not `link.substring(0, 38)`? Is there something special about these sort of links that you want to account for in a general way? If so, please describe it (e.g. "I need everything up until a 3-digit number following the `/payments/` route, and here's what I tried as a [mcve]"). Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: the /454 is the unique id of the user. so what if the digit changes for example to /4564?

Comment: Since there is no specification as to what your requirements are, I gave a simple answer that works on the only example given. What exactly do you need? Matching on `/^.+\/\d+(?=\/)/` might work, but it's just a guess. I have no idea what format we're dealing with, so please describe it along with possible edge cases and provide a variety of examples. Otherwise, it's anyone's guess. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

try to use `substring()` :

```dart
  String link = 'http://sales.local/api/v1/payments/454/ticket/verify?token=jhvycygvjhbknm.eyJpc3MiOiJodH';
  String delimiter = '/ticket';
  int lastIndex = link.indexOf(delimiter);
  String trimmed = link.substring(0,lastIndex);
  //print(trimmed);
```

Comment: A substring approach won't work if the "454" part of the URL is any shorter or longer than three characters which will be likely if it is an ID.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
main(List<String> args) {
  String str =
      'http://sales.local/api/v2/paymentsss/45444/ticket/verify?token=jhvycygvjhbknm.eyJpc3MiOiJodH';

  RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"((http|https)://sales.local/api/v\d+/\w.*?/\d*)");
  String matches = exp.stringMatch(str);
  print(matches); // http://sales.local/api/v2/paymentsss/45444
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comments, a trim approach won't work here because you don't know how much to trim off. The ID portion of the URL may not be guaranteed to always be three characters.

Instead of trying to trim the parts of the URL you don't want, use a regular expression to match only the parts that you **do** want:

([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vfu67R/1))

```dart
final url = 'http://sales.local/api/v1/payments/454/ticket/verify?token=jhvycygvjhbknm.eyJpc3MiOiJodH';
final pattern = RegExp(r'^http:\/\/sales\.local\/api\/v1\/payments\/(\d+)');
final match = pattern.firstMatch(url);

final shortUrl = match?.group(0);
final id = match?.group(1);

print(shortUrl); // "http://sales.local/api/v1/payments/454"
print(id);       // "454"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    input string print for Flutter: 

       String str2 = "-hello Friend- "; 
    print(str2.trim()); 



    Output Print : -hello Friend- 

NOte: Here last space remove from string.
    1.Right Method: 

    var str1 = 'Dart';
    var str2 = str1.trim();
    identical(str1, str2);

    2.Wrong Method
    '\tTest String is Fun\n'.trim(); // 'Test String is Fun'
```

Comment: Don't answer the question based on the title text only. Read the question text to understand what OP is actually asking.